# average of binned values

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I have 2 separate dataframes and want to do correlation between them

```
Time  temperature   |   Time  ratio
0        32         |    0        0.02
1        35         |    1        0.1
2        30         |    2        0.25
3        31         |    3        0.17
4        34         |    4        0.22
5        34         |    5        0.07
```

I want to bin my data every 0.05 (from ratio), with time as index and do an average in each bin on all the temperature values that correspond to that bin.

I will therefore obtain one averaged value for each 0.05 point
anyone could help out please? Thanks!

****edit on how data look like**** (df1 on the left, df2 on the right)

```
Time     device-1    device-2...   |   Time    device-1    device-2...
0        32            34          |    0        0.02       0.01
1        35            31          |    1        0.1        0.23
2        30            30          |    2        0.25       0.15
3        31            32          |    3        0.17       0.21
4        34            35          |    4        0.22       0.13
5        34            31          |    5        0.07       0.06
```

Comment: How would your expected output look like?

Comment: I want to plot temperature vs ratio. and because I have a lot of data points I want to average temperature value for each 0.05 interval values of ratio

Comment: but those 2 parameters are on 2 different datasheet, I created a df corresponding to each of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work with the `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temp = [32,35,30,31,34,34]
ratio = [0.02,0.1,0.25,0.17,0.22,0.07]
times = range(6)

# Create your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': times, 'Temperature': temp, 'Ratio': ratio})

# Bins
bins = pd.cut(df.Ratio,np.arange(0,0.25,0.05))

# get the mean temperature of each group and the list of each time
df.groupby(bins).agg({"Temperature": "mean", "Time": list})
```

Output:

```
             Temperature    Time
Ratio
(0.0, 0.05]         32.0     [0]
(0.05, 0.1]         34.5  [1, 5]
(0.1, 0.15]          NaN      []
(0.15, 0.2]         31.0     [3]
```

You can discard the empty bins with `.dropna()` like this:

```
df.groupby(bins).agg({"Temperature": "mean", "Time": list}).dropna()

             Temperature    Time
Ratio
(0.0, 0.05]         32.0     [0]
(0.05, 0.1]         34.5  [1, 5]
(0.15, 0.2]         31.0     [3]
```

EDIT: In the case of multiple machines, here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_machines = 3
# Generate random data for temperature and ratios
temperature_df = pd.DataFrame( {'Machine_{}'.format(i): 
                                 pd.Series(np.random.randint(30,40,10)) 
                               for i in range(n_machines)} )

ratio_df = pd.DataFrame( {'Machine_{}'.format(i): 
                           pd.Series(np.random.uniform(0.01,0.5,10)) 
                          for i in range(n_machines)} )

# If ratio is between 0 and 1, we get the bins spaced by .05
def get_bins(s):
    return pd.cut(s,np.arange(0,1,0.05))

# Get bin assignments for each machine
bins = ratio_df.apply(get_bins,axis=1)

# Get the mean of each group for each machine
df = temperature_df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(bins[x.name]).agg("mean"))
```

Then if you want to display the result, you could use the `seaborn` package:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_reshaped = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index')
df_reshaped.columns = [ 'Ratio bin','Machine','Mean temperature' ]

sns.barplot(data=df_reshaped,x="Ratio bin",y="Mean temperature",hue="Machine")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. Tis is very helpful but what if temperature and ratio are in 2 different dataframes? I have 60 columns corresponding to 60 different machines that measure these parameters on each datasheet. I did what you said for binning the ratio for all my machines but I don't see how to link it with the temperature measurements that are in the second dataframe.

Comment: To concatenate your dataframes, `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` should work

Comment: Great this worked. Sorry I have tried to simplify the problem but the data look a bit more complicated. Now I have indeed 120 columns (60 from each df). column names are as follow: machine 1, machine 2, machine 3.., and this twice since each time one is from ratio and the other one from temperature. I am still stuck with how to correlate the binning of ratio and the temperature data.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. It would help with if you could put an example with 2 machines and show the expected output

Comment: I just did an edit on my original question. each df has same column names (I have measurements for 60 devices, thus 60 columns + 1 for time). one gives temperature measurements, one give ratio. Is it clearer?

Comment: And you want the mean temperature in each bin for each machine?

Comment: yes exactly I want average of temperature for each  bin of ratio for each machine.

Comment: But the average for each machine separately, or all machine combined?

Comment: average for each machine separately.

Comment: this is amazing thank you so much!!!
 I have one last question.
df=temperature_df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(bins[x.name]).agg("mean"))
 I have created a column called bin, with a=np.arange(0.05, 1.05, 0.05)
df['bin']=a
I can plot one machine by one machine as follow:
df.plot(x='bin', y='device-1')
But how could I iterate through every machine column vs bin and plot all of them successively?

Comment: I added an example of barplot witth seaborn

Comment: Thank you very very much. you were really super helpful